# Implement 3rd payment gateway such as VNPay, Napas for in-app purchase in Vietnam

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, payment-gateway

Now I am developing an app for signing up courses (including paid and free courses), also users have to pay monthly fee membership. I know that I can only use Apple Pay for an in-app purchase app that has digital content and products.

We target users that are over 40, and most of them do not have a credit card like Mastercard or visa, they just use domestic banking cards like Vietcombank, MB Bank,.. so payment via Apple Pay is not an appropriate option for us. So how do I submit an app like this using a third-party payment gateway from Vietnam?

Thank you

Comment: If your use case requires in app purchase then you cannot use any other payment method, but don't confuse IAP with Apple Pay.  They are different things.  IAP is billed to the payment method the user sets up with their Apple ID.  This could be a credit card, Apple Gift Card etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only required to use In-App Purchase if the item is consumed in/using the app.

This means that if your app is only used for signing to courses that are not given using the app, you can implement a 3rd-party payment system.

Same should apply to the membership; there should be no (valuable) content made available in the app for which users pay this membership.

This is covered in the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#person-to-person-services).  Have a good read of the related guidelines.

Good luck with your courses!